# Browse hard disk files on a corrupted windows installation

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Few days ago, I stumbled on a problem that required a bit of indepth knowledge to get things working. I have a PC setup that has no CD disk drive. I turned off my computer, that was running on Windows, mid-updating (I know I should not have done this) and then it didn't want to start again.

How can I browse files without wiping all my data or giving it to a computer specialist first?

Comment: I would create a USB bootable version of Hirens Boot CD - this will allow you to view your files, and copy anything you may need over to a USB    http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk

Comment: @user2676140 Thank you, I wanted to add this as a self-answered question. Since I think it's pretty useful approach I found.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to browse the files is to pull the drive out and mount it as the second drive on another machine. You can also buy a $10 SATA case that connects to the computer via USB and mount it up that way.

You can also download a bootable image for CD or USB such as Hiren's Boot CD, Knoppix, Puppy Linux, or System Rescue CD.

There are also several different ways to repair the Windows installation, but that's not what you're asking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no CD Disk Drive, just put put a bootable USB drive with a Windows installation.

The first screen appeared:

[image: Image is not mine.]

Then chose **Repair your computer**.

From the second screen:

[image: Image is not mine too.]

Select the option that opens **Command Prompt**.

In command prompt type:

> notepad

Which launches the notepad application.

From there chose **Open>File...** and you will be able to browse your hard drive files.

It's not really convenient, but you can use it as a file explorer and transfer between folders and copy them to an external storage device (another USB).